# ERROR in Entry Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '*source*'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp

[image]

I am following a course on Udemy which is about Wordpress development. Following the course I came up with this problem, I was trying to add google maps to a custom post type, for that I needed to update javascript file. But whenever I am running 'gulp scripts', this error occurs. I have no idea about node, gulp, webpack. I am just following the course. I looked up on the internet for a long time on this issue but found nothing.

I am using XAMPP. And before this, 'gulp watch' was working fine and php scripts were getting updated just fine.

**gulpfile.js:-**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
settings = require('./settings'),
webpack = require('webpack'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
rgba = require('postcss-hexrgba'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
colorFunctions = require('postcss-color-function');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'css/style.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, rgba, colorFunctions, autoprefixer]))
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error.toString()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.themeLocation));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
  webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    }

    console.log(stats.toString());
    callback();
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function(done) {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    proxy: settings.urlToPreview,
    ghostMode: false
  });

  gulp.watch('./**/*.php', function(done) {
    browserSync.reload();
done();
  });
  gulp.watch(settings.themeLocation + 'css/**/*.css', gulp.parallel('waitForStyles'));
  gulp.watch([settings.themeLocation + 'js/modules/*.js', settings.themeLocation + 'js/scripts.js'], gulp.parallel('waitForScripts'));
  done();
});

gulp.task('waitForStyles', gulp.series('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'style.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}))

gulp.task('waitForScripts', gulp.series('scripts', function(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb()
}))
```

**webpack.config.js:-**

```
const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    App: settings.themeLocation + "js/scripts.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js"),
    filename: "scripts-bundled.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  mode: 'development'
}
```

**settings.js:**

```
exports.themeLocation = '/wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
exports.urlToPreview = 'localhost/imuni';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error the solution is simple add a DOT before /wp-content/:

```
exports.themeLocation = './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
exports.urlToPreview = 'localhost/imuni';
```